# Jquery: Getting undefined error when trying to find element in td on hover

Tags: jquery

I have attached hover event with my table td and trying to read few span id and value but getting undefined error.my td looks like.

```
<td class="text-right  note FYA-col  right-cell-border  right-cell-border no-bottom-border">
<span style="display:none" id="load_64_41" class="hover-note">Loading...</span>
<a data-id="EPS, GAAP" href="javascript:void(0)" class="my-lineitem  stat-toggle">$10.57</a>
<span data-header="2019 FYA" id="com_64_41" class="comment_sign"></span>
</td
```

i am trying to find this way but getting undefined error. where i am making the mistake?

here is my js code

```
$('#dataMatrixAll td').hover(

                // This first function is our mouse over function
                function()
                {
                    //alert('IN');
                    period = $(this).closest().attr('data-header');
                    elementid = $(this).closest().attr('id');
                    alert(elementid);
                    res = elementid.split("_");
                    rowid = res[1];
                    loaderid = 'load_' + res[1] + '_' + res[2];

                    alert('line item ' + $("#lineitem_" + rowid).text() + ' header text ' + period + ' loader text ' + $('#' + loaderid).text());
                    //alert($('#' + loaderid).text());
                    $('#' + loaderid).show();
                },

                // This first function is our mouse out function
                function()
                {
                    //alert('OUT');
                    $('#' + loaderid).hide();
                }
            );
```

1. I need to get id value from span whose class is hover-note on hover td

Loading...

2. need to get data-header value on hover td

please help me with some sample code.

i tried this way too but still getting undefined error.

```
$('#dataMatrixAll td').hover(

                // This first function is our mouse over function
                function()
                {
                    //alert('IN');
                    period = $(this).closest().find('span.comment_sign').attr('data-header');
                    elementid = $(this).closest().find('span.hover_note').attr('id');
                    alert(elementid);
                    res = elementid.split("_");
                    rowid = res[1];
                    loaderid = 'load_' + res[1] + '_' + res[2];

                    alert('line item ' + $("#lineitem_" + rowid).text() + ' header text ' + period + ' loader text ' + $('#' + loaderid).text());
                    //alert($('#' + loaderid).text());
                    $('#' + loaderid).show();
                },

                // This first function is our mouse out function
                function()
                {
                    //alert('OUT');
                    $('#' + loaderid).hide();
                }
            );
```

thanks

### Edit

Tried this way too but no luck

```
$('#dataMatrixAll td').hover(
  // This first function is our mouse over function
  function()
  {
    //alert('IN');
    //var period = $(this).closest('span.comment_sign').attr('data-header');
    //var period = $(this).closest('.comment_sign').attr('data-header');
    var period = $(this).parent().closest(".comment_sign").attr("id");
    alert(period);

  },
  // This first function is our mouse out function
  function()
  {
    //alert('OUT');
    $('#' + loaderid).hide();
  }
);
```

only need to fetch element from the TD on which mouse over. here js fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/35aszhw6/

please help me where i made the mistake. thanks

Comment: You need to give `closest()` a selector. It won't return anything if you give it nothing to actually search for

Comment: yes i used selector like span with in closest but still got undefined. `$(this).closest('span').find('.comment_sign').attr('data-header');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please see my edited portion and also provide jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code you have use selector as `td` so when you write `.next('span')` there is no span tag after `td` that's the reason its giving you **undefined** .Instead you can use `a` as selector and then simply use `$(this).next('span').attr('data-header');` to get the attribute value .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#dataMatrixAll td a').hover(function() {
//getting next sbling
  var period = $(this).next('span').attr('data-header');
  console.log("first way"+period);
  //or  getting span from closest td
  var period1 = $(this).closest("td").find('span.comment_sign').attr('data-header');
  console.log("second way"+period1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataMatrixAll" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>
      <span style="display:none" id="load_64_41" class="hover-note">Loading...</span>
      <a data-id="EPS, GAAP" href="javascript:void(0)" class="my-lineitem  stat-toggle">$10.57</a>
      <span data-header="2019 FYA" id="com_64_41" class="comment_sign"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the job this way.

```
    var period = '';
    var elementid = '';
    var res = '';
    var rowid = '';
    var loaderid = '';
    var loadingtext = '';
    var lineitem = '';
    var section = '';

    $('#dataMatrixQuarter td').hover(

        // This first function is our mouse over function
        function () {

            //alert($(this).index());
            $('.hover-note').hide();
            elementid = $(this).closest('td').find('span.hover-note').attr('id');
            //alert(elementid);

            if (elementid != undefined) {
                loadingtext = $(this).closest('td').find('span.hover-note').text();

                if (loadingtext.indexOf('Loading') != -1) {
                    //$(this).closest('td').find('a.my-lineitem').attr('data-id')
                    res = elementid.split("_");
                    rowid = res[1];
                    loaderid = 'load_' + res[1] + '_' + res[2];


                    section = $('select[id=Section-btn]').val();
                    lineitem = $("#lineitem_" + rowid).text();
                    //period = $(this).closest('td').find('span.comment_sign').attr('data-header');
                    var th = $('#dataMatrixQuarter th').eq($(this).index());
                    var headerText = th.text();

                    $('#' + loaderid).show();
                    //alert('section ' + section + ' line item ' + lineitem + ' period ' + headerText);

                    $.ajax({

                        url: "/Tuning/GetCommentForPeriod",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            Section: section,
                            LineItem: lineitem,
                            Period: headerText
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            //want to return data as not boolean but string here
                            //alert('comment '+data);
                            if (data != '') {
                                $('#' + loaderid).text(data);
                                $('#' + loaderid).show();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (a, b, c) {
                            alert("Error")
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#' + loaderid).hide();
                    $('#' + loaderid).text('Loading...')
                }
            }
        },
        // This first function is our mouse out function
        function () {
            $('#' + loaderid).hide();
            $('#' + loaderid).text('Loading...')
        }
    );
```